# Problemas al abrir archivo Word ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Resulta que quiero abrir un archivo Word (más adelante voy a trabajar con Excel), la cuestion es que estoy utilizando el siguiente codigo para abrir el archivo:

```
[HttpGet]
public void abrirXX()
{
   Process.Start(@"C:\Users\X usuario\Downloads\Documento.docx");
}
```

Tengo 2 consultas:

1) Cuando lo abro usando "debug" me abre el archivo correctamente, cuando publico el proyecto y toco el boton para abrir el archivo no pasa nada. (Solo aparece el icono de Microsoft Word en el administrador de tareas), por que pasa esto? (De que no abra en publicado)

2) Digamos que ya abre publicado, como hago para abrir este mismo archivo en otra PC?

Gracias

Comment: En mvc solo puedes descargar el archivo, recuerda es una aplicacion web solo puedes enviar el archivo a una peticion de usuario, Tu peticion HttpGet  no puede ser declarada como void.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando lo ejecutas en Debug, se ejecuta con tu usuario local y por eso se te abre el documento.

Cuando lo ejecutas en Release, se ejecuta con el usuario del IIS por eso tu usuario no ve el documento. Si lo ves en el administrador de tareas debería poner que el usuario es otro.

De todas formas, el documento lo abre en el servidor. Quieres que el documento se abra desde otro PC, para eso tienes que devolver el archivo en el servicio. Pero NO puedes hacer que se abra automáticamente ya que no puedes ejecutar procesos en el cliente. Por razones de seguridad, si no podrias ejecutar código malicioso en el cliente. Imaginate enviarle un fichero .exe y abrirlo ...

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult abrirXX()
    {
            return PhysicalFile(@"C:\Users\X usuario\Downloads\Documento.docx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    }
```